# How to delete rows in Dataset that contain specific values (efficiently)

Tags: filtering, dataset

consider this `Dataset`:

```
dataset = Dataset[{
     <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>
   , <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y",  "c" -> {2, 3}|>
   , <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {3}|>
   , <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "c" -> Missing["Unmatched"]|>
   , <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> Missing["Unmatched"], "c" -> {9} |>
   , <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>
}]
```

I want to delete all rows that contain `Missing["Unmatched"]`.

## Question:

> What is an elegant way of performing this operation?

My real dataset is 300 MB and has 50 columns. The `Missing["Unmatched"]` values can occur in any column.

## Example of a large dataset

```
bigDataset = Dataset@Table[
                           <|"a" -> j
                           , "b" -> RandomChoice[{RandomInteger[{0, 9}], Missing["Unmatched"]}]
                           , "c" -> RandomChoice[{RandomInteger[{0, 9}], Missing["Unmatched"]}]
                         |>
                         , {j, 1, 1000000, 1}];
```

Comment: It will be difficult to give you accurate performance comparisons against your file if we don’t have an example of the same size/complexity to test possible solutions upon; though, I think you may have realized this, but it is worth mentioning in any case.

Comment: @CATrevillian good point. I have added an example of a large dataset similar to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing on your sample data `dataset`:

```
r1 = DeleteMissing[dataset, 1, 1]
```

Takes `0.000530041` second

```
r2 = dataset[Select[Not@AnyTrue[#, MissingQ] &]]
```

Takes `0.000412052` second

```
r3 = dataset[Select[Not@MatchQ[#, KeyValuePattern[{_ -> _?MissingQ}]] &]]
```

Takes `0.000428904` second

All have the same result:

```
r1 == r2 == r3

(*Out: True *)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

one way to do this is:

```
Dataset@DeleteCases[
                    Normal[dataset],
                    <|___, _ -> Missing["Unmatched"], ___|>
                 ];
```

which takes $2.32$ seconds on `bigDataset` (in my question)

## Benchmarking @BenIzd 's methods and my own[image]